# EF core treating readonly properties as NULL on Insert

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm struggling to understand why ef core are treating readonly fields as null, I have the following property on my model.

```
private readonly string _name;
public string Name => _name;
```

When I add my entity to the DBContext and try to save changes, An exceptions is throw because Name cannot be null.

The only way I find to this work is to define on ModelCreating that this property has a colunm name.

```
p.Property(pr => pr.Name).HasColumnName("name");
```

Doing so, this works OK.

I want to know if someone knows why EF core is mapping such property to NULL.

Thanks in advance

PS: I know that this will not work when the EF core tries to build the entity model, but this wasn't supposed to work in terms of saving the entity?

Comment: What matters is, does the property ever get a value? Which is only possible by initialization in the constructor. I don't see how explicit mapping can make a difference, unless EF's default mapping creates a not-null column and the fluent mapping a nullable one. Maybe it works that way, never tried yet.

Comment: Yes, I set the value by constructor.